# Refresh private queue when main queue changes in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I have two managed object contexts in my application, one of type NSMainQueueConcurrencyType, the other a temporary NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType for background work.

I couldn't find the official solution to the following situation: When the private queue is doing some background work while the main queue deletes an object, I get an uncaught exception "Core Data could not fulfill a fault" when accessing this object in the background queue since it was deleted.

This is an expected behavior, however I am wondering how to handle these cases without getting a fault exception. I'm thinking this can be fixed by listening to the "NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification" notification and then merging the background context with the main context but is this really the best way to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, observe the did-save notification, and merge the changes with

```
[context mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
```

Also, you want to make sure you have setup an appropriate merge policy.